# Replace duplicate value in dataframe row with NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks something like this:

| index | c1 | c2 | c3 | m1 | m2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | c | a | c |
| 2 | d | e | f | d | a |
| 3 | a | b | c | d | e |

For each row the values in c1, c2, c3 will never be duplicates of each other, same with m1 & m2
My aim is for each row to only show each value once, i.e if a values in m1 or m2 already exists in c1, c2 or c3 it should be replaced with NaN.

So for the example I gave, the result would be:

| index | c1 | c2 | c3 | m1 | m2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | c | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | d | e | f | NaN | a |
| 3 | a | b | c | d | e |

How would this best be solved?
Thanks

Comment: the only thing I can think of is to do `df.T.duplicated(subset=[1])` and loop over the parameter for `subset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy to perform broadcasting comparison:

```
# get "c" columns (you can use another method)
# and convert to numpy array
c = df.filter(regex='^c').to_numpy()
# get "m" columns (you can use another method)
m = df.filter(regex='^m')

# mask values in "m" that are also in "c" in any position
mask = (m.to_numpy()[...,None] == c[:,None,:]).any(-1)

# update dataframe
df[m.columns] = m.mask(mask)
```

output:

```
   index c1 c2 c3   m1   m2
0      1  a  b  c  NaN  NaN
1      2  d  e  f  NaN    a
2      3  a  b  c    d    e
```

intermediate `mask`:

```
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [False, False]])
```

Answer (score 0):

presuming you want a `np.nan` just stack to get a series and then then unstack and replace with the value you want.

```
df.mask(df.stack().duplicated().unstack(), np.nan)
```

This would be dependent on the order of your columns and with different sets you could just copy out the columns into another dataframe

Comment: I don't think this will work unless you subset the correct index